# Android: String and a shared Preference string not matching

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am grabbing a String from text file on a url and saving it to sharedPreferences ... then the next time it grabs the String, it compares it against the old one stored in shared preference and if its different it notifies the user.

I am getting the string from url fine and its saving in sharedPreferences, but when I try to compare them with an if (x == y) statement it always results as not the same;

Here is the onPostExecute()

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String Input;
    String oldInput;
    Input = result.toString();
    oldInput = currentSavedSettings();
    if (Input == oldInput){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "fixed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        savePrefs("CURRENT_SETTINGS_FILE", Input);
        //the toasts were used to ensure that neither were returning null
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, oldInput, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, Input, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // the following is commented out until I fix this issue
        //createNotification();
    }   
}
```

and the currentSavedSettings which is getting the old CURRENT_SETTINGS_FILE

```
private String currentSavedSettings() {     
    SharedPreferences sp =
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    String result = sp.getString("CURRENT_SETTINGS_FILE", null);
    return result;
}
```

and for good measure here is what i am using to save the SharedPreference

```
private void savePrefs(String key, String value) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
    Editor edit = sp.edit();
    edit.putString(key, value);
    edit.commit();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.equals` or `.equalsIgnoreCase` to compare strings.

For more info

[How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @MasterZangetsu glad to help what is 3 pints?

Answer (score 0):

**Did you try this,**

```
passcode == pref_passcode // is not the same according to Java

String passcode;

pref_passcode.contentEquals(passcode); //try this or

pref_passcode.equals(passcode)
```

**You should always use one of these to compare string. do not use equal signs (==)**